What would falsify relativity?
The motivation of this question comes from quantum mechanics. In quantum mechanics, two particles that are very far apart from each other can behave in correlated ways. Specifically, this happens when they are entangled. Generally, this implies some sort of communication between them.
According to the no communication theorem though, you cannot send a signal to take advantage of this, and thus it is used to imply that no communication between these particles occurs (which would have to be faster than light).
But this theorem assumes that relativity is true. But if communication was occurring between particles faster than light, wouldn’t that imply relativity is false? How does one know then if relativity is falsified here or not?
Lastly, the theorem says that we are not able to send a signal and take advantage of this, but I don’t see how it then follows that the particles are not communicating with each other faster than light.

Take a look at Bell's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem

That seems to be a physics question, not a philosophy question. You seem to be asking whether a hypothetical result of a hypothetical experiment could invalidate Einstein's theorem,. The answer is hypothetically yes, but we need all the details of the experiment and the result, and the experiment and results would have to be replicated and analyzed in detail, before we could say whether it does or not. An anomalous result could be because we were not testing what we thought we were testing, or analyzing the results correctly.  Take it up with the physicists, not philosophers.

The no-communication theorem is derived in non-relativistic quantum mechanics, so it does not assume relativity. And it does not say anything about us specifically. It says that no information can be transferred faster with entanglement than without it if the axioms of QM hold. That is how one knows that any prediction of QM is consistent with relativity. Not that it matters since QM is only an approximation of QFT, which is independently confirmed and explicitly relativistic. Since we have experimental reasons to believe QFT we have those same reasons to disbelieve FTL communication.

I’m voting to close this question because the question is about physics, not philosophy.

@Conifold if a non local theory of QM like Bohmian mechanics is true, then relativity would be false. So the entanglement experiments can be demonstrated to confirm the falsity of relativity or allow ways to still work around it. How does one differentiate between these?

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3158/why-is-quantum-entanglement-considered-to-be-an-active-link-between-particles and all the linked questions, to see this is a mere duplicate.

@Conifold From the wiki: “It asserts that during the measurement of an entangled quantum state, it is impossible for one observer to transmit information to another observer, regardless of their spatial separation.” So this is about a measurement of one observer affecting the other, not the particles communicating between each other faster than light in principle

"Observers" and "measurements" are the pop-sci language, which stands for interactions with classical systems and collapse. On mathematics of QM, I suggest consulting more competent sources than Wikipedia.

@Conifold here is a paper that argues that the no signalling theorem is circular: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9906036. “ However, we claim that most or all no-signalling proofs published to date are question-begging, in that they depend upon assumptions about the locality of the dynamics of the measurement process that are the very points that need to be established in the first place”

Why do you want to know?

@ScottRowe He wants to know something that will validate his false beliefs about relativity and superluminal communication.

Syed, Is there any way to vote NOT to close? You're getting the same raw deal rhat everybody else gets who doesn't toe the line. == The fact that you're confused and don't understand relativity, that don't enter into it. You shouldn't be muffled.

@MissUnderstands if non locality is true, then relativity is violated. You have not shown that non locality is false, which entanglement experiments seem to imply

@MissUnderstands: Voting not close is done by voting to reopen if it does get closed. Yes, it might be better to do open/close by running totals, perhaps even to say closed iff/while down votes exceed up votes by a certain margin, but that's not how SE is currently set up.

@MissUnderstands: Agreed in principle, but some of these overstep either general Stack Exchange practice or the guidelines of this stack (SE tries to do Q&A, not extended discussion or argumentation, unlike Reddit), and general SE policy is that out of bounds things should be closed and either edited into appropriate form before reopening or referred elsewhere. Analysis of the reasons for or correctness of review decisions belongs on the Meta stack , https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/ or open the ”..." menu and select Philosophy Meta). Caveat: metas do discuss, sometimes bluntly.

@MissUnderstands: Again, I am not an admin here, but I have been elsewhere and I understand what on/off topic lines folks are trying to draw. I'm not sure the SE model really works well for this topic, but it's what we've got. Advance warning: one of the meta questions was triggered by my having misunderstood something you said, and I apologize.

Agree with MissUnderstands. This should have been (or perhaps still could be!) migrated to Physics SE to be properly answered. If it's VTCed without an accepted/understood answer, then the asker will think either a) that they should stay away from SE in general (probably not what anyone wants, if we want to help them) or b) that their claims about relativity being unfalsifiable are justified and being suppressed by the "physics community".

Relativity makes an extremely broad range of extremely specific predictions - more or less all of macroscopic physics excluding chemistry, including the common sense physics that gets everyone through their daily life. Anything that deviates from those predictions would falsify it (although it would require significant replication to overcome the likelihood of human error, etc). This could range from getting an obscure measurement that deviates in magnitude from the predicted value by slightly more than the computed error of the prediction, to observing your transfigurations professor turn herself into a housecat in defiance of conservation laws.

Falsification doesn't mean we ball up a working theory, throw it in the trash, and act like we know nothing. Usually it means adding a correction factor, shrinking the domain, or modifying the mathematical structure.

+1 relativity would make Popper proud in its falsifiability :)

Sure but how do we differentiate between the entanglement experiments falsifying relativity or not?

The predictions of physics are falsified routinely and no one thinks that it falsifies physics; instead it is assumed to be an error in measurement or in experimental setup, or a misunderstanding of some sort.

@DavidGudeman: Or it is eventually accepted as a case the existing theory doesn't cover, and more research is done to try to find out why and adjust the theory. Physics can't be falsified because it is all provisional. Individual theorems can, but that's why they are called theorems rather than laws, even when we are pretty darn sure of them to an obscene level of precision and over a huge range of cases.

@keshlam, er, they are called laws by most people, not theorems. And defenders of science are always claiming that science changes when it has been proven wrong, but that's true of every doctrinal tradition, they just have different epistemologies of what constitutes a proof that they are wrong. Science is only superior in this aspect if you begin with the assumption that scientific epistemology is superior.

Sadly this good answer answers the badly chosen title of the question, not it's actual content.

"Anything that deviates from those predictions would falsify it" - counterpoint, we observe that galaxies have a lot more mass than relativity predicts. Instead of saying "relativity is wrong", we say "hmm, must be dark matter".

@TKoL We do say "relativity is wrong" (as a standalone cosmological theory). Even the relativity-preserving ones like Lambda-CDM are not relativity, they're relativity plus stuff. Falsification doesn't mean we ball up a working theory and throw it in the trash, rend our garments, and scream at the sky, lost and rudderless in an incomprehensible universe. Usually it means adding a correction factor or shrinking the domain. ...That might be worth adding to the answer.

"relativity plus stuff" seems fundamentally different from "relativity is wrong" to me.

@TKoL If you need "plus stuff", it's wrong without "plus stuff". If you're looking for relativity being fundamentally irrecoverably wrong about everything at every reasonable approximation, relativity is unfalsifiable, because it's mostly true, even if Harry Potter shows up and starts turning people into housecats and having real time conversations with his friends in Andromeda.

But that's not what falsifiable usually means in this context. If you want a different word, that's fine with me. Definitions are arbitrary.

Adding dark matter to relativity isn't the sort of 'plus stuff' that would make relativity meaningfully wrong. Relativity doesn't say anything about what type of stuff is in the universe. It just says, if that stuff has mass, this is how that mass interacts with spacetime.

Re laws: Still common usage but I'd consider it outdated terminology. And even laws are subject to revision when they don't work. The important thing here isn't the term, but that science always admits there may be a better answer rather than assuming it has reached The Ultimate Answer,  never mind The Ultimate Question. This frustrates folks who demand certainty, but it seems to be the best tool we have for getting progressively closer to complete truth or complete confidence in our answers (which are not necessarily the same thing).

@TKoL I agree with that part; dark matter by itself is a corrective term to a hypothesis including relativity (relativity and certain rules for estimating the mass of distant objects) but it modifies the rules for estimating mass, not the relativity part.  (As opposed to Lambda-CDM, which is mathematically distinct from just relativity with different mass estimates.)

@Syed If we measure FTL information transfer, it would falsify relativity. Mathematical physics has nothing whatsoever to say about in-principle-unmeasurable communications, because everything we know how to say in the language of mathematical physics is how to load measurements into a model, how to translate the mathematical result into a measurement prediction, and what model to use to do that.

Special relativity is a theory about the nature of spacetime. If it is true, then objects with non-zero positive mass cannot move relative to each other at speeds greater than or equal to c. The theory could be falsified by any experiments that showed massive particles moving at speeds greater than c. Entanglement experiments don't show that, so no need to panic as yet. It's possible we might find some new phenomena that cause SR to be dropped in favour of something better- there are many precedents for theories being retired in physics.


It's possible we might find something new that causes SR to be dropped == It wouldn't be dropped; it would be extended. ==   there are many precedents for theories being retired. == Dropping a theory is exceedingly rare. It happened with the Bohr atom and Geocentricism. And it'll happen with this "multiverse," as soon as y'all wise up. == But more often, the established theories turn out to be  special cases of more general theories, like Newton not accounting for relativistic effects. == If SR turns out to be wrong, it will only be wrong in an outer context that we don't know about yet.


Entanglement doesn't disprove relativity, it demonstrates that, as Einstein said but everyone ignores, elapsed time is negative spatial distance.

As time keeps on slipping into the future, the value of t in the above equation continually increases.
After a nanosecond of time, the location of the point is now c times one nanosecond away from where it was. This is almost exactly 12 inches. It's how far light moves in a nanosecond.
After that short time, the location of what was a point at t-zero, has now become the collection of all points in space (all combinations of xyz) that add up to a distance of one light-nanosecond — which looks like a sphere about two feet wide.
This sphere of light is called a light cone. It's the path that light takes when it leaves a flashbulb. In four dimensions it looks like a cone, but in three dimensions, it looks like a sphere expanding at the speed of light.
It doesn't look like a cone to us because the long dimension of the cone is elapsed time, and we can't see in that direction.

Point masses trace a world-line through Minkowski space, but the photon's path is a world-sphere.
For a four dimensional location to remain the same location at a future time, it has to exist as the surface of an expanding sphere.
If you interact wth this 2-foot diameter light sphere on 2 opposite sides, you're observing the same 4D point event from two different locations in space from a nanosecond later in time.
That's the reason the spins correlate.
No information travels from one side of the sphere to the other, which would be superluminal. But nothing is even transmitted from the original point to the outside of the sphere one foot away.
In entanglement, no distance is actually traversed by anything.
The positive distance in space only looks unusual because you can't see the negative distance in time. Your brain doesn't subtract the negative distance.
So no, entanglement does not violate special relativity. Rather, it lets us see the beauty of the inverse relationship between space and time.
BTW, This expansion of points into expanding spheres happens with mass as well as photons. Mass increases the density of spacetime. That's how mass stores energy in space. That distortion of the metric  appears to propagate outward as a gravity wave.
But when you feel the pull of the moon, you're not feeling something emitted by the moon one second ago, you're interacting with the real physical moon that exists at your location now, but it exists one second in the past.
The fact that it is actually in your past is why it is stretched out as a wave now.
The the same thing happens in reverse when a wave function collapses into a point and  interacts. But that's what happens on the bottom of the standard picture of the light cone, where time runs from bottom to top and the points of 2 cones are in the middle.

The bottom half is a collapsing wave function. In the middle is a point mass, and the cone above the point is the expanding gravity wave.
As the spherical wave function collapses, its deviation from the spherical null path is the information it contains. That information is the sum of the path integral that adds up to create this wave function.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

At one time it was common to teach SR with an imaginary time coordinate, which made the metric look like a 4d Euclidean distance, but that died out because it didn’t carry through to GR.

@ProfessorSushing That's interesting. In what way did it not carry through to GR? == Was it treating the time as imaginary instead of negative? I'll bet that's it. Imaginary becomes negative when you square it, which you do ecery time you use it.

If I come up with a candidate theory to explain A and my theory is inconsistent with the experimental facts that support relativity, then it’s my theory that’s wrong, not SR.

@ProfessorSushing Yes, but I asked in what way it was inconsistent, and you declined to tell me. I even asked politely. I think. You're not complaining about it, so I probably wasn't rude.
